# Are opinion-based questions allowed on meta?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question, meta

When a question related to security is opinion-based, can we ask it on meta?  And can we ask opinion-based question on meta in general?

Comment: You're always welcome to drop by the DMZ (in chat) and ask whatever questions you want there.  Of course you're not guaranteed and answer, but you aren't guaranteed one on the actual site anyway...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meta is about asking about questions, it's not for asking off-topic questions.

Questions need to be able to have a chance at a single acceptable answer that is also going to be useful to others. Asking for opinions and people's experiences are just not a good fit on a Q&A site.